# Unable to start e2e tesing in angular project

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

Running e2e testing on my angular project throws.

My chrome version : Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (x86_64)

I have enabled auto-update in my chrome browser. Seems like the issue occurs after the browser update.

```
ng e2e
```

```js
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: 'myip', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[17:00:29] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: 'myip', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (my-project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (my-project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at my-project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (my-project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (my-project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (my-project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (my-project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Local.getNewDriver (my-project/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (my-project/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at my-project/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (my-project/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at my-project/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (my-project/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[17:00:29] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

my protractor config file.

```js
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: [ "--no-sandbox", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1600,900" ]
    }
  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Please help.

Comment: Possibly mismatch of ChromeDriver/Chrome

Comment: How do I correct ChromeDriver ? I am not able to change my chrome version.

Comment: you can manually select a chrome driver when using webdriver manager by using `npm run webdriver-manager update=87.0.4280.141`

However, I believe that. the newest webdriver doesn't work out of the box for some people. I'm experiencing issues with this specific Chrome version myself.

It is possible to downgrade your chrome version, btw. For example, this is the link to all Windows chrome executables https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/

Comment: Hey thanks @endqwerty. I have tried also by downgrading my chrome browser. Nothing worked out. Finally i fixed my issue using https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the issue by editing node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/files/file_manager.js

Update file_manager.js #line-no-166 fileUrl.url = fileUrl.url.replace(/_m1/, '');

Github issue: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/476

Answer (score 0):

Ah, that makes sense. I solved it by manually placing a copy of the chrome webdriver into the downloaded directory instead of using the executable that webdriver-manager downloads.