# unable to upload folder with files using protractor for web application testing

Tags: protractor

Iam using protractor for testing my web application that has  a button to popup window to open file explorer where I need to select a folder that contains 5 files that needs to be uploaded.
I have the code as
''''

```
var fileUpload = '/home/indu/jpg';
require("./logger");
console.file("./test.log");
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileUpload);
fs.readdir(absolutePath, (err, files) => {
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        
        
          filelst.push(fileUpload +"/"+files[i]); 
      
     }
     console.log("fuull is ",filelst);
    
}); 
var remote = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');
browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());


var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileUpload);  

console.log("value of absolutePath",absolutePath);
 var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

// Unhide file input
 browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px';  arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileElem.getWebElement());

fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

when I execute I get below error

*Failed: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Error during upload, redirecting to login page .... }
(Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110): Error during upload, redirecting to login page ....
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'indu-Latitude-E6420', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-91-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_312'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown*

I have tried on windows10 as well as ubuntu 18.04.05 and on both I get chrome driver info version unknown error. I have searched for this error and tried suggested solution in
[Unable to start e2e tesing in angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65628312/unable-to-start-e2e-tesing-in-angular-project/70566374#70566374)
but that didnt work too.
Pls suggest

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/308#issuecomment-206006812

Comment: I have following warning popup "This will upload all files "jpg" folder. Only Do this if you trust this site"  from chrome. How to handle this. I tried all the solutions suggested above but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by a

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buttonelementlocator), 
100, 'Element is not clickable.').then( () => {
                
                uploadfiles();
            }); 
 function uploadfiles(){
   
  var shell = require('shelljs');
 


var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
// uploadfile.bat contains the autoit exe to upload the files and handle 
chromebrowser alert
var task = shell.exec('uploadfile.bat');

if (task.code !== 0) {
    console.log("execute AutoIt script fail: " + task.stdout);
    shell.exit(1);
}
```

}